# Magento 2.1 Customers Address Book Not Displayed Properly

Tags: magento-2.1, customer-address

Newly installed Magento 2.1 does not display customers address book properly both in frontend `customer/address` and backend customer information > customer view.

The data is stored and displayed properly in backend customer information > addresses, though.

Is this a bug or there's something missing from my end?

[image]
[image]

**Update**:
Looks like this is known bug as reported in:

- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5873#issuecomment-236868255
- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5681

Comment: Can you please publish the solution ? i struggle the same issue

Comment: Hi @Goldy, I gave up and never troubleshot it again. Patching couple latest version didn't fix the issue. Haven't tried clean reinstall though.

Comment: you can follow this : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5873 maybe it will help you if you still struggle this issue

Comment: Thanks. Sadly, based on the last comment posted 7 hours ago, the solution still did not work.